# RDLC Report Data Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I have a problem with my RDLC report in ASP.Net.

This is my code for my function to convert to pdf:

```
    public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType, int reportId)
    {

        LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
        localreport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report_Reservatie.rdlc");

        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet_Reservaties";
        reportDataSource.Value = storeDB.Reservaties.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ReservatieId == reportId);

        localreport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        string reportType = ReportType;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        if (reportType == "PDF")
        {
            fileNameExtension = "pdf";
        }
        else
        {
            fileNameExtension = "jpg";
        }
        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;
        byte[] renderedByte;
        renderedByte = localreport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment:filename + reservaties_report." + fileNameExtension);
        return File(renderedByte, fileNameExtension);
    }
}
```

and this my code in my View:

```
@model int
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Checkout Complete";
}
<h2>@MyApplication.Resources.ResourceNL.CheckoutComplete</h2>
<p>@MyApplication.Resources.ResourceNL.ThankForTheOrder: @Model</p>

@Html.ActionLink("Export to PDF", "Reports", new { ReportType = "PDF",             reportId = @Model}, null)
```

But I still get this errormessage:

***The report data source object must be of the type System.Data.DataTable, System.Collections.IEnumerable, or System.Web.UI.IDataSource.***

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? I really can't find the problem...

Comment: What kind of type is returned by this query: `storeDB.Reservaties.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ReservatieId == reportId);`? The data source type should be `DataTable` or `List` to pass in `ReportDataSource`, you may need `ToList()` after `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Thx for you answer Tetsuya. The returntype is Integer, and how can i put this ReportDataSource into a DataTable?

Comment: Well, certainly you can't pass an integer as a `ReportDataSource` data source. You need to pass entire part of data source as either `DataTable` or `List` based on applied `Where` criteria. Learn how to create `DataTable` from LINQ using `CopyToDataTable()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset).